# jQuery or CSS selector to select all IDs that start with some string

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

How can I select all elements whose `id` starts with "player_"?

I have multiple elements like this:

```
<div id="player_290x3dfda">text</div>
```

Every `id` has a unique stamp on it. How can I select all those elements, either with jQuery or with pure CSS?

Comment: use this http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Normally you would select IDs using the ID selector `#`, but for more complex matches you can use the attribute-starts-with selector (as a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector), or as a CSS3 selector):

```
div[id^="player_"]
```

If you are able to modify that HTML, however, you should add a class to your player `div`s then target that class. You'll lose the additional specificity offered by ID selectors anyway, as attribute selectors share the same specificity as class selectors. Plus, just using a class makes things much simpler.

Comment: Is this selector in CSS works on older browsers like ie8 and ie9, and if not what the alternative?

Comment: It's very compatible - check out quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link3

Comment: what if you don't know the type of html element? like it could be an input, or select, etc.

Comment: @And Wan: Then leave out the type selector. It's not required.

Comment: Using a class for functionality is a bad practice! CSS is for styling! What if the class names changed because new styles were implemented? Then all of your functions would break!

Comment: @Raqem: https://blog.novalistic.com/archives/2018/01/using-css-selectors-for-non-css/#attributes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701670/can-i-use-non-existing-css-classes/18701712#18701712

Answer (score 97):

try this:

```
$('div[id^="player_"]')
```

Comment: This should be the answer.  It shows how to actually implement the solution in code.  Thanks, Prakash!

Answer (score 25):

You can use meta characters like `*` (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
So I think you just can use `$('#player_*')`.

In your case you could also try the "Attribute starts with" selector:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/: `$('div[id^="player_"]')`

Comment: Actually I believe that you can't use *$('#prefix\*')*. At least I don't get it to work...

Comment: This doesn't work for me (in Chrome).

Comment: Well I think you don't understand what the documentation says:
To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~` ) _**as a literal part of a name**_, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div[id ^= "player_"]');
```

This worked for me..select all Div starts with "players_" keyword and display it.