# jQuery find ID with variable component

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery or css selector? select all id’s that start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-select-all-ids-that-start-with)

This code changes `#idview`'s `src` attribute on mouse-over of ids 1-3.

```
$("#id_1, #id_2, #id_3, #etc").mouseover(function(){
    $("#idview").attr("src","id_" + this.id.substr(3,4) + ".jpg");
});
```

How can I select an ID by "#id_" and then a variable integer? Say for example if there were 1000 images, where it would be impractical to write this out long hand?

It may be something like `$("#id_"+*)`?

Comment: how do you change source? based on the id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='id_']").mouseover(function () {
    //Do stuff
});
```

It would be a little more efficient to clarify the element type before the attribute selector, but it's not clear from your question exactly what elements you're trying to select.

Comment: Ah brilliant, didn't think of this approach. Thanks. The element types are both images if that helps?

Comment: @idb - You're welcome, glad I could help. In that case, just add `img` before the attribute selector: `img[id^='id_']`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply incorporate the variable integer into a string:

```
var integer = 2
    myid = "id_" + integer;

$( "#" + myid ) // Selector
```

Although if you don't need to target specific IDs then I would go with James' answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="id_"]').mouseover(function(){
    $('#idview').attr('src', this.id + ".jpg"));
});
```

Or you can add a class to the elements you want to bind and then use it as selector.

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
    //...
});
```