# jQuery select every id with certain beginning

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery or css selector? select all id’s that start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-select-all-ids-that-start-with)

I need to select all the elements with ids that start with `"Monday_"`, example `id="Monday_16"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
$("[id^='Monday_']");
```

or better:

```
$("tagname[id^='Monday_']");
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to accomplish that:

```
$('[id^="Monday_"]')
```