# What does "^=" (caret equals) mean in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following hides images that have `Stud_Btn` in their id.

```
$('img[id^="Stud_Btn"]').hide();
```

even if I have `Stud_Btn1234` and `Stud_Btn234`, it will still hide it. What does "^" really mean?

Can it not only be used for comparison? Or does it have other uses?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: All available selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: What Chevi said. Did you not try Googling jQuery selectors?

Comment: Even [searching SO for `[jquery] "^="`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+%22%5E%3D%22) would have revealed some use cases.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy and FelixKling Google sucks at small searches.. Read my Edit..
thanks for replying though.. I appreciate the time you've given..

Comment: @user2128576 Try [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/) for searching for special characters!

Comment: @user2128576: Google "jQuery selectors" - 4th link down is the official jQuery documentation. No need to search for the symbols. Scroll down on that page and find Selectors > Attributes. Click this and ^= is the 7th one down.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Thanks! this is Really useful too.
I will pin this to my browser so I won't have to search it again.
thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery or CSS selector to select all IDs that start with some string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-to-select-all-ids-that-start-with-some-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[attr^=val]` a CSS selector that means:

> Element that has an attribute named `attr` with a value that starts with `val`.

It's similar to `[attr$=val]`, which does the opposite, looking for an attribute ending with `val`.

Answer (score 7):

It's an [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). Your specific example will match any `img` element whose `id` attribute starts with the string "Stud_Btn".

The jQuery API documentation is the best place to go for simple questions like this. I would strongly recommend spending a bit of time reading through it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply sir :)
Though you are right, but I don't have the time to do so read all of what's in the documentation. I am a student working on a project :)

Thanks for replying though, my experience here in stackoverflow.com has been great thanks to people like you :))

Answer (score 2):

It gets all the images that have their Ids **starting with** `Stud_btn`

Answer (score 2):

It means "attribute starts with", see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

It means "startes with". Continue reading [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).