# How to initialise JQuery script for dynamically generated ids

Tags: php, jquery

EDIT:: My brain's smoking :) Perhaps I'm looking at this from the wrong angle? We need the JQuery to initialise for each dynamically generated id. Do we have to run the JQuery for each and every id (ie. place it in our PHP loop)??

How can we make this JQuery script apply to a dynamically generated list of ids where the ids increase by 1 when looped with PHP?

Here's the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#slider').unoslider({
                scale: 'true', 
                responsive: 'true',
                touch: 'true',
                preset: 'bar_fade_left',
                navigation: {autohide: true},
                slideshow: {speed: 5, timer: false},
                animation: {delay: 200}
  }); 
});
```

And here the dynamically generated ids:

```
<?php echo "<ul id="slider'.$counter.'" class="unoslider">";?>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Use the class selector (`$('.unoslider')`) instead of the ID selector?

Comment: Use `$('ul.unoslider')` instead. If you need to get the number portion of the ID in JS, simply use the substring of the ID attribute.

Comment: Your id should fit the <li> or <ul> element ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery or css selector? select all id's that start with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-select-all-ids-that-start-with)

Comment: @Yellow Bird : id should fit every <li> element which has the format slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple plugin which lets me initialize elements based on `data-*` attributes:

```
<?php echo "<ul data-jquery-bind='unoslider' ".
    "data-jquery-options='" . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($unoSliderOptions), ENT_QUOTES) . "'>;"?>
```

Here is the plugin:

```
$.fn.jqueryBind = function() {
    return (this.length ? this : $('body')).each(function() {
        var $root = $(this);
        $root.find('[data-jquery-bind]').each(function() {
            var jqueryFn = $(this).attr('data-jquery-bind');
            var options = $(this).attr('data-jquery-options');
            if (options) {
                options = $.parseJSON(options);
            }
            $(this)[jqueryFn](options);
        });
    });
};
```

Then add:

```
$(function() {
    $.jqueryBind();
});
```

And it will automatically search for elements with the attribute `data-jquery-bind` and initialize the plugin using the json serialized options in `data-jquery-options`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector -

```
$('ul[id^="slider"].unoslider')
```