# Get id's containing a string

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to get all id's that contain a given string. The full id is not known, only a partial id. Id's appear like so:

```
<td class="item" id=shipping-1 align="left">$1.00</td>
<td class="item" id=shipping-2 align="left">$6.49</td>
<td class="item" id=shipping-3 align="left">$8.50</td>
// etc...
```

As you can see, "shipping-" is a constant, but the appended number is dynamic on page load (depends on what shipping options are valid for the receiving address).

I'm not great with javascript, but obviously using `getElementById()` won't work here.

I would like to avoid doing something clunky like getting id's in a loop until I get an 'undefined'.

I need something like: `getElementsContainingString('shipping-')`

I need to get an array of these id's, then will read the innerHTML and determine which is cheapest. This must be done dynamically via javascript because we cannot control the page on the server side to perform this logic.

Comment: I suggest you to use the `data` attribute instead of `id`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery or css selector? select all id's that start with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-select-all-ids-that-start-with)

Comment: Are they all going to have the same `class` (like in your example)? You could get them all with `document.getElementsByClassName` and glean `id`s from there.

Comment: yes, they all have the same class. only id's and the innerHTML vary. this may be worth a shot.

Comment: did you try a loop and `document.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this must work on as many browsers as possible, otherwise management won't allow it. We still get ie7 users... and the occasional ie6 user... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="shipping-"]');
```

[No jQuery required](http://vanilla-js.com). This does a CSS selector for `id="shipping-[wildcard]"`. [MDN: Query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), [MDN: Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). This works with IE 8+, and there are polyfills if you want to support lower.

Comment: does this work on all (or most) browsers? we still get ie7 and the occasional ie6 shopper.

Comment: mate that will only work with IE8+ im sure about that.. but IE6 wow what do they sell? stuff for 99 y o people! :O

Comment: @jycr753 lol, you'd be surprised who's shopping (or attempting to shop I should say) online these days.

Comment: thanks, I think this is going to be the "best fit" answer. maybe I can convince management that our small ie6 userbase can deal with the old way of displaying rates (fall-back sort of thing).

Comment: you can always check in orders, if they actually make some orders, places, and shipments.. that way you can save the way out.. or depending of your market.. ;) there is always a i way to push those people out! and force them to download a real browser @SnakeDoc

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>IE sucks! If you use IE then you suck too!<![endif]-->`

Comment: @jycr753 you'd be shocked at how many users still show up on our pages with javascript disabled... but I digress... *sigh*

Comment: @SnakeDoc wow I just put a header with red lines to get a real browser... and just for fun...
`<!--[if gte IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ie/ie-8-funnyppl.css">
<![endif]--> `and not support for bellow that... lol

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery, you can use the following code :

```
var cells = $("td[id^=item]");
```

The brackets `[]` tells to take all td with the attribute *id* starting with string *"item"*.

Comment: I'm sure is not td[id^=item] but td[id^=shipping]

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this answer: [Javascript getElementById base on partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string)

You'll then want to use their second fiddle's example: http://jsfiddle.net/xwqKh/1/

They used the following code (not my own):

```
document.findElementsWithIdLike = function(prefix) {
    var results = [];
    findChildrenWithIdLike(document.body, prefix, results);

    return results;
};

window.findChildrenWithIdLike = function(node, prefix, results) {
    if (node && node.id && node.id.indexOf(prefix) == 0) {
        //match found
        results.push(node);
    }

    //check child nodes
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = node.childNodes[i];
        var childResult = findChildrenWithIdLike(child, prefix, results);
        if (childResult) {
            results.push(childResult);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
  if (tds[i].id.indexOf("shipping") == 0)
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a css selector `[attrName^="startsWith"]`

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td[id^="shipping-"]');
```

Seems to be available from `IE7+` and the rest of the browsers.

Sample here :  http://jsbin.com/kayov/1/edit