# JQuery - go down with selector name

Tags: jquery

I created this code:

```
$("input[name*='Gridview1$ctl02']").each(function () {
   if(this.type == 'checkbox'){
       if(this.checked == true){
           alert("test")
        }
       else
        {
           alert("test2")
        }
    }
})
```

Its good when I write this `$("input[name*='Gridview1$ctl02']")` but I need array of `ct101,ct102,ct103`

### [image]

**I need Something like this:**

```
$("input[name*='Gridview1']").find("ct").each ...
```

Comment: You are finding ct character which is present in name ? Which won;t work by find method. 
Find search for element inside the main element.

Comment: The mark-up you've posted would suggest that `$("input[name*='Gridview1$ct1']")` would meet your needs?

Comment: Can't you use a "begins with" selector, like `input[name^="Gridview1$ct"]`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-to-select-all-ids-that-start-with-some-string

Comment: I will check this answer input[name^="Gridview1$ct"]

Comment: @Mark Leiber it`s ok thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple create a selector to match any element where their name starts with Gridview1:

```
$("input[name^='Gridview1']").each(function () {if(this.type == 'checkbox'){if(this.checked == true){alert("test")}else{alert("test2")}}})
```

Alternative if you want only text inputs:

```
$("input[name^='Gridview1'][type='text']").each(function () {if(this.type == 'checkbox'){if(this.checked == true){alert("test")}else{alert("test2")}}})
```

Comment: I will give you points for your time but Mark gave correct answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should match all the names you require AND those that are checked checkboxes:

```
$("input[name^='Gridview1$ctl'][type='checkbox']:checked")
```

---

See it here (it will alert names of checked checkboxes after you hit Test):

```js
function test() {
  $("input[name^='Gridview1$ctl'][type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Gridview1$ctl01" />
<input type="text" name="Gridview1$ctl02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Gridview1$ctl03" />
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I see you got all the answers by the time I finished writing mine so I updated it to show you how to do everything with a single selector.

Comment: Thanks one more time :)